# How Can i normalize matrix 760x760 in matlab to contrast with new range = [0-255]?

Tags: matlab

I'm a newbie in matlab, and have a matrix in size 768x764 and I want to normalize its values to be in range [0 - 255] ? how can I do this ?

Comment: Applying a scaling factor based on the max value? Histogram equalization? Note that this is not a uniquely defined task.

Comment: Subtract the min to get the range to start at 0, divide by the range to normalise to [0,1], then times by the desired max (255): `M=( (M-min(M(:)))/range(M(:)) )*255`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can download MATLAB R2017b, the new function [`rescale`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rescale.html) is a convenient way to do this.